# Moviepy - video will not export with the audio I add to it

Tags: python, moviepy

```
from moviepy.editor import *


clip = VideoFileClip('add_audio.mp4')

audio = AudioFileClip('liver_1.wav')

videoclip = clip.set_audio(audio)

clip.write_videofile('does this work.mp4')
```

Please help, when I run this code the video exports but with no audio. I've tried many different formations of this with slightly different functions and still nothing works. I have yet to find someone with this issue.

Comment: The issue ended up being that Macs won't play certain codecs I think. I uploaded the video to YouTube and there was audio even though when I played it on my desktop it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can add encoding as argument in `videoclip.write_videofile` like this:

```py
videoclip.write_videofile('sample.mp4', codec='libx264', audio_codec='pcm_s32le')
```

As it's explained in the [documentation](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html#moviepy.video.VideoClip.VideoClip.write_videofile), you can change video and audio codec when you writing video:

> ## codec
>
> 'libx264' (default codec for file extension .mp4) makes well-compressed videos (quality tunable using ‘bitrate’).
>
> 'mpeg4' (other codec for extension .mp4) can be an alternative to 'libx264', and produces higher quality videos by default.
>
> ## audio_codec
>
> Which audio codec should be used? Examples are ‘libmp3lame’ for ‘.mp3’, ‘libvorbis’ for ‘ogg’, ‘libfdk_aac’:’m4a’, **‘pcm_s16le’ for 16-bit wav and ‘pcm_s32le’ for 32-bit wav**. Default is ‘libmp3lame’, unless the video extension is ‘ogv’ or ‘webm’, at which case the default is ‘libvorbis’.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `clip.write_videofile` when you need to do `videoclip.write_videofile`.  You are saving the unmodified original.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I believe that was a mistake on my end when I cut my code down to put up here. Nonetheless I tried that and it still doesn't work